# Необходимо ли программисту знать, как вычислять производительность алгоритмов?

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ", там большой упор делается именно на это. Можно ли это пропустить или это прям мастхев?

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

P.S. Извиняюсь за, скорее всего, глупый вопрос)

Comment: Нужно иметь представление как считается производительность и какие есть способы ее увеличения. Так что читайте, пригодится.

Comment: Достаточно научиться (на основе знания сложности базовых алгоритмов) правильно прикидывать сложность конкретной реализации. И соответственно иметь возможность "на глаз" сравнить сложности двух реализаций.

Comment: Как мне кажется, если нужно что-то оптимизировать на уровне кода, то необходимо уметь анализировать его (код) и находить те места, из-за которых все ПО будет проседать по производительности. Ну и соответственно, уметь избавляться от таких проблемных мест.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не планируется писать собственные алгоритмы, достаточно знать сложность базовых алгоритмов (быстрая сортировка лучше сортировки пузырьком или Шелла и т.д.)

Это пригодится в спортивном программировании, например, в олимпиадах от Яндекса.